# ¿Cómo realizar un conteo de entrada y salida en SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net, visual-studio, .net

Estoy intentando realizar un conteo de tramos, es decir, de un TRAMO A(que sería de entrada determinadas por una IP) y otro TRAMO B(que sería de salida determinadas por otra IP). En este caso los datos serían enviados mediante XML desde un IPAddress(que sería una cámara que me envia el dato). Una vez entre un vehículo por la entrada se sumaría, pero cuando el mismo vehícula salga, debería restar.

Esta es la query que he realizado pero no me sale como yo quiero :

```
SELECT matricula, ipaddress, COUNT (*) AS conteo
FROM Acceso_general (base de datos general)
WHERE fecha_hora < DATEADD (day, -1, GETDATE()) 
GROUP BY matricula , ipaddress
HAVING COUNT (*) = 1
ORDER BY matricula
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cómo se sabe, en tu diseño, si es una `entrada` o una `salida`? Si es posible, crea [un fiddle con un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: ¿Cómo diferencias las entradas y las salidas? Sin conocer ese detalle nada podremos hacer para el caso que expones. Tampoco se entiende bien qué es lo que quieres, si es totalizar por un lado las entradas y por otro las salidas. Pulsa en [edit] y aclara tu pregunta.

Comment: Perdón Cedano, serían mediante la IPAddress, es decir, son dos IP's diferentes que una sería de entrada y otra de salida. Quizá no sea eso lo que me dices.

Comment: Ya, si las entradas y salidas se determinan por una IP conviene decirlo en la pregunta: *las entradas se determinan por la IP tal y las salidas por la IP tal*. Explicado eso, tampoco queda claro si lo que quieres es totalizar las entradas por un lado y las salidas por otro, obteniendo dos columnas, algo como `totalEntradas` y `totalSalidas`. La pregunta es confusa, porque parece que quieres eso, pero luego hablas de sumar o restar cuando entre o salga ¿? Pon un ejemplo del resultado que esperas, pues no se entiende.

Comment: Tengo una tabla que había creado como "Conteo" con filas de IN, OUT y STAY(los que quedan dentro de ese tramo). Pero claro, no sé como realizar la lógica o relacionar esa tabla para que haga ese conteo que ando buscando.

Comment: Tú puedes relacionar tus tablas por la columna en común que tengam (supongo que la matrícula). Como te dije más arriba, crea un fiddle con un pequeño set de datos de las tablas y explícanos con claridad que es lo que quieres, pues aún no logro entender si quieres totalizar entradas y salidas o qué es lo que quieres. Mientras más claridad haya más pronto podremos ayudarte.

Comment: No funciona Cedano para poner el fiddle. Una cosa, podría contactar contigo de forma personal? No logro salirme con ello. Necesito ayuda.

Comment: Es mejor que preguntes por aquí, yo o cualquier otro usuario te ayudará no hay problema. Si no sabes como crear el fiddle, comparte la estructura de las tablas implicadas en la pregunta, eso lo puedes obtener ejecutando el comando: `SHOW CREATE TABLE aquiElNombreDeLaTabla;` Es que para responder de la mejor manera necesitamos ver cómo son las tablas, y si muestras un pequeño set de datos se agradece. Eso agiliza la respuesta, porque de lo contrario tendríamos que re-crear todo y además adivinando, porque no sabemos cómo se relacionan tus tablas.

Comment: @A.Cedano ese comando no existe en SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacer un conteo en el que unos valores sean positivos y otros negativos, no podemos usar `COUNT(*)`. O bueno, sí podríamos pero necesitamos hacer 2 consultas. Lo más eficiente es usar la operación para sumar y restar. Si estás pensando en `SUM()` estás en lo correcto. Dentro de esa función, solo hay que poner la condición para saber si es positivo o negativo. Dejo un ejemplo algo genérico puesto que no sé cual sea la ip de entrada y cual la de salida, pero te indica la estructura general para que solo apliques la condición correcta.

```
SELECT matricula, 
       SUM( CASE WHEN ip_es_entrada = 1 THEN 1
                 WHEN ip_es_salida = 1 THEN -1 
                 ELSE 0 END) AS conteo
FROM Acceso_general
WHERE fecha_hora < DATEADD (day, -1, GETDATE()) 
GROUP BY matricula
--HAVING COUNT (*) = 1
ORDER BY matricula;
```

Comment: Luis y para hacer un UPDATE? Es decir, que haya una actualización constante de los datos de conteo? Porque será a tiempo real, creo que es uno de los proyectos más complejos y encima estoy solo. Soy programador junior pero en SQL voy algo cojo.