# Convertir un Strg en INT, para operación algebraica SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

¡Hola amigos del código!

El día de hoy vengo con una gran duda, y es que necesito contabilizar el Número de operaciones de Compras y restarlo con las Devoluciones.

Deseo hacer eso gracias al Codigo del cliente, el problema es que este código está en formato String o cadena, por lo que, quisiera poder realizar la operación entre Compras - Devoluciones.

Tengo una columna donde se mezclan:

**Las compras como 'A' y devoluciones como 'B'**

Si las solicito así.

```
Select *
FROM -
WHERE TipoFactura IN ('A', 'B')
```

Tendría como resultado algo como:

```
CodUsuario  Coste  TipoFactura  Sucursal    Mes     Año
--------------------------------------------------------
 0002        25        A          0001       02     2022
 0003        30        A          0001       02     2022 
 0004        35        B          0001       02     2022
```

Mi objetivo esperado es tener algo como:

```
Compras    Mes     Año  Sucursal
----------------------------------
   2       02      2022    0001
```

Donde si nos damos cuenta, para el mismo mes, año y sucursal serían 3 transacciones, pero, como una fue una devolución entonces de 3-1 = 2

Mi código está formado algo como:

```
    SELECT
    COUNT(CodClie)
  --,dAY(FECHAE) dia
    ,MONTH(FECHAE) mes
    ,YEAR(FECHAE) año
    ,Sucursal
--TipoFactura 

FROM 
    -

WHERE 
   TipoFactura IN ('A', 'B')
group by
    
   --DAY(FECHAE)
    TipoFactura
    ,MONTH(FECHAE)
    ,YEAR(FECHAE)
    ,Sucursal
    
ORDER BY 
    Sucursal DESC
    ,MONTH(FECHAE)
```

¿El problema?

es que sí cuento efectivamente las transacciones pero no logro restarlas porque son un String, intenté hacerlo mediante

```
--CASE WHEN TipoFactura = 'A' THEN CAST(CodCliente AS INT) ELSE CAST(-CodClienteAS INT) END
```

Pero no funcionó y el resultado que obtengo es (con mi código):

```
Compras  TipoFactura Mes   Año  Sucursal
-----------------------------------------
 2000         A       02  2022    0001
  05          B       02  2022    0001
```

Y debe ser simplemente:

```
 Compras  TipoFactura  Mes   Año   Sucursal
 -------------------------------------------
  1995         A       02    2022    0001
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?
y **gracias de antemano**

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! haces un sum.. del case... donde si es A, sumas 1.. y si es B, restas 1.... viene por ese lado...no contas otras cosas....

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo realizar un conteo de entrada y salida en SQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/531345/c%c3%b3mo-realizar-un-conteo-de-entrada-y-salida-en-sql)